# Accessing earlier values in odeint

Tags: systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I'm having some trouble using odeint function from scipy. I'm translating a discrete system into a continuous one, but some equation in the discrete model requires that I access to the previous value of a variable that I'm currently integrating. How could I translate this behaviour?

```
import numpy as np
days_of_prediction = 15
N = 100
discrete_S0 = np.zeros((days_of_prediction, 1))
discrete_I0 = np.zeros((days_of_prediction, 1))
discrete_Q0 = np.zeros((days_of_prediction, 1))
discrete_H0 = np.zeros((days_of_prediction, 1))
discrete_D0 = np.zeros((days_of_prediction, 1))
discrete_S0[0] = 99
discrete_I0[0] = 1
discrete_Q0[0] = 0
discrete_H0[0] = 0
discrete_D0[0] = 0
v=0.1
alpha = 0.3
gamma = 1/21
psi = 0.2
k_h=0.1
k_q=0.1
eta_h=0.3
eta_q=0.3
 for t in range(days_of_prediction - 1):
 discrete_S0[t + 1] = discrete_S0[t] - v * discrete_S0[t] * discrete_I0[t] / (N - discrete_Q0[t] - discrete_H0[t] - discrete_D0[t])
discrete_I0[t + 1] = discrete_I0[t] + v * discrete_S0[t] * discrete_I0[t] / (N - discrete_Q0[t] - discrete_H0[t] - discrete_D0[t]) - gamma * discrete_I0[t] - alpha * discrete_I0[t] - psi * discrete_I0[t]
discrete_Q0[t + 1] = discrete_Q0[t] + alpha * discrete_I0[t] - eta_q * discrete_Q0[t] - k_h *discrete_Q0[t] + k_q * discrete_H0[t]
discrete_H0[t + 1] = discrete_H0[t] + psi * discrete_I0[t] - eta_h * discrete_H0[t] + k_h * discrete_Q0[t] - k_q * discrete_H0[t] - zeta * discrete_H0[t]
discrete_R0[t + 1] = discrete_R0[t] + eta_q * discrete_Q0[t] + eta_h * discrete_H0[t]
```

I've posted a snippet of the code, the problem is with the denominator of the first two equations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"requires that I access to the previous value of a variable"*: This is called a delay-differential equation - DDE. scipy does not have procedures for that. Try JitCDDE, PyDStool or sundials. // But I do not see that in your Euler code. On the right side I only see the index `[t]` for the computation of the `[t+1]` values.

Comment: yes, because I'm converting the code to a continous system, so I need to access to past values

Comment: You convert $v_{n+1}=v_n+h·f(v_n)$ to $\dot v=f(v)$ or, to be closer to the discrete iteration, $\dot f = f(v)-\frac{h}2·f'(v)·f(v)$. There is no delay involved, everything is at the same time and state.

Comment: so how could I substitute the denominator of the first two equations? putting Q0,H0 and D0?

Answer (score 0):

From the interaction terms you can directly read off the ODE system
\begin{align}
\dot S &= \nu\frac{S·I}{N-H-Q-D} 
\\
\dot I &=-\nu·\frac{S·I}{N-H-Q-D} - \gamma·I - \alpha·I - \psi·I
\\
\dot Q &= \alpha·I - \eta_q·Q - \kappa_h·Q + \kappa_q·H
\\
\dot H &=  \psi·I - \eta_h·H + \kappa_h·Q -  \kappa_q·H - \zeta·H
\\
\dot R &=  \eta_q·Q + \eta_h·H
\end{align}
If you now solve that with the Euler method with step size $1$, you get the discrete method back. However, if you simualate that with any other method, that is, get closer to the exact ODE solution, the result might be distinctly different. Compare [Question about Euler's Method and the SIR epidemic model using a spreadsheet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642671/) for a similar question (only backwards, from ODE to large-step Euler) on the basic Zombie Apocalypse model.

Comment: The solver of odeint is lsoda, so the results are different, according to your reply.  I could compare the solution and figure out the best one