# ODE equivalent to a system of Difference Equations (Discrete to Continuous time)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, discrete-optimization, discrete-calculus, differential-games

Consider the following gradient-descent ascent system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
 x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \eta \nabla_{x} g(x_{k}, y_{k}) \\
 y_{k+1} = y_{k} + \eta \nabla_{y} g(x_{k+1}, y_{k})
\end{cases}$$
The main idea is that player $x$ plays first and then $y$ gets to respond; observe that $y_k$ depends on $x_{k+1}$. Were it not for the latter, the system could become a simple ode by letting the stepsize $\eta \rightarrow 0$:
$$\begin{cases}
\dot x = - \nabla_x g(x, y) \\ \dot y = + \nabla_yg(x,y)
\end{cases}
$$
But this is not the case.
What should I do may be obvious but I cannot see it yet. Any ideas how could I convert it to a continuous problem?

Comment: Do you have a specific example where the ODE system gives a qualitatively wrong solution? Note that the difference between computing $y_{k+1}$ with $x_k$ vs. with $x_{k+1}$ is $O(η^2)$. Note that quantitatively, the order 1 Euler method will usually quickly move away from the exact solution.

Comment: I am trying to make a differential game out of a simple matrix game using Grad.Descent-Ascent, so I don't really have a ground truth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the lines of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3642860/115115,
try to use a perturbation approach, set
\begin{align}
\dot x&=-g_x+ηf\\
\dot y&=g_y+ηh
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
x(t+η)&=x(t)-ηg_x+η^2f-\tfrac12η^2(g_{xx}\dot x+g_{xy}\dot y)+O(η^3)
\\
y(t+η)&=y(t)+ηg_y+η^2h+\tfrac12η^2(g_{yx}\dot x+g_{yy}\dot y)+O(η^3)
\end{align}
To get this mostly similar to the step equation of the discrete method, one would have to chose
$$
f=\tfrac12(-g_{xx}g_x+g_{xy}g_y)
$$
and using that
$$
y_{k+1}=y_k+ηg_y(x_k-ηg_x,y_k)=y_k+ηg_y-η^2g_{yx}g_x+O(η^3)
$$
one gets to
$$
h=-\tfrac12(g_{yx}g_x+g_{yy}g_y)
$$
So in total, the exact solution of
\begin{align}
\dot x&=-g_x-\tfrac12η(g_{xx}g_x-g_{xy}g_y)\\
\dot y&=+g_y-\tfrac12η(g_{yx}g_x+g_{yy}g_y)
\end{align}
should follow $O(η^2)$ close the path of the discrete system. Or reverting the Taylor expansion to avoid using second order derivatives
\begin{align}
\dot x&=-g_x(x+\tfrac12ηg_x(x,y),\,y-\tfrac12ηg_y(x,y))\\
\dot y&=+g_y(x-\tfrac12ηg_x(x,y),\,y-\tfrac12ηg_y(x,y))
\end{align}