# How to take the proper limit of this Markov Chain?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, markov-chains, markov-process

I am trying to understand how to take the limit of the following Markov chain taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d$, i.e. how to formulate the continuous time version:

$x_i = \sqrt{1-\beta_i}x_{i-1} + \sqrt{\beta_i} z_{i-1},\quad  i=1,\dots,N,$

where $z_{i-1} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$, and $\beta_i$ are positive parameters.

I know the solution already, its:

$dx = -\frac12 \beta(t) x dt + \sqrt{\beta(t)} dW$

However, I am struggling to derive this limiting behavior for $N \to \infty$.

Here is my naive approach:

Let $\Delta t = \frac{1}{N}$. We simply reindex the chain through $t\in \{0,1,\dots, \frac{N-1}{N} \}$ and consider

$x_{t+\Delta t} = \sqrt{1-\beta_{t+\Delta t}}x_{t} + \sqrt{\beta_{t+\Delta t}} z_{t} $

However, this will not lead to the desired result for $\Delta t \to 0$. In the original derivation, which can be found in Appendix B of the paper [Score-Based Generative Modeling through Stochastic Differential Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.13456), they do the following:

They rewrite the chain as

$x_i = \sqrt{1-\frac{N\beta_i}{N} } x_{i-1} + \sqrt{\frac{N\beta_i}{N}} z_{i-1},\quad  i=1,\dots,N,$,

define $\beta(t) := \lim_{N\to \infty} N \beta_i$, and thus for $t\in \{0,1,\dots, \frac{N-1}{N} \}$,

$x_{t+\Delta t} = \sqrt{1-\beta_{t+\Delta t} \Delta t}x_{t} + \sqrt{\beta_{t+\Delta t}\Delta t} z_{t} $

which indeed leads to the desired result for $\Delta t \to 0$ after taylor expanding $\sqrt{1-x}$ for $x\to 0$.

I find the definition of $\beta(t)$ unintuitive. However, this is crucial for the appearance of $\Delta t$ and therefore the right limiting behavior. Could someone walk me through the reasoning?

In another example, they describe the limiting behaviour of

$x_i = x_{i-1} + \sqrt{\sigma_i^2-\sigma_{i-1}^2} z_{i-1}$

as follows:

$x_{t+\Delta t} = x_t + \sqrt{\sigma_{t+\Delta t}^2-\sigma_{t}^2}z_{t}$

hence, they simply replace every index with $t$. Why is this possible here, but not in the first case where this naive approach fails?

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider that $ΔW(t_i)=(W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1}))=\sqrt{Δt}z_{i-1}$, which suggests that $\beta_i=\beta(t_i)Δt$. After that
$$
\sqrt{1-\beta_i}=\sqrt{1-\beta(t_i)Δt}=1-\frac12\beta(t_i)Δt+O(Δt^2).
$$
There is always some arbitrariness when converting a discrete process into some hopefully related continuous process. To hit the discrete process more exactly with the continuous process some correction terms involving $Δt$ might be necessary.

For a weakly related ODE example see [Question about Euler's Method and the SIR epidemic model using a spreadsheet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642671/question-about-eulers-method-and-the-sir-epidemic-model-using-a-spreadsheet), in some way reversing the difference from the Euler method to the midpoint method to get an equation with an exact solution that follows closely the Euler points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, your argument would also suggest that the discrete chain I mentioned at the end will turn into:
$$x_{t+\Delta t} = x_t + \sqrt{(\sigma_{t+\Delta t}^2-\sigma_{t}^2) \Delta t}z_{t}$$
which it does not.

I understand that from cont. to discrete there are many different, valid ways to do it. I am just confused about how to do it the other way around.

Comment: Could you also elaborate on _"There is always some arbitrariness when converting a discrete process into some hopefully related continuous process."_ ?

Comment: No to the first, there you get $Δx_t=\sqrt{2σ_tσ'_tΔt}z_t=\sqrt{2σ_tσ_t'}ΔW_t$, this is much more organic than the first example. To the second, there is no canonical way to go from discrete to continuous (without increasing the dimension, and even then there is no unique construction). One could look at the recursion formula for the sequences $\{x_{2n}\}$, $\{x_{4n}\}$ etc. and try to find some function with $\alpha(x_{i+1})=\alpha(x_i)+1$ that can then serve to interpolate for fractional indices. But that might run into conceptual problems.